# Paypal iOS: How to get User billing/Shipping address when we get return_url with Express Checkout with toke and payerId

Tags: ios, express, paypal, checkout, returnurl

I'm trying to integrate the PayPal ExpressCheckout SDK in my iOS (Swift 3) app.

I'd like to be able to to get the payPal EC token and redirect to PayPal site, and get back to Return URL with the Token and PayerId appended.

How can I get all of the information such as the shipping address?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to do and what you have tried?